# Connecting two different data sources pivots with single slicer

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have multiple pivot tables in the same tab from different tab data sources (all in a single excel file). All the pivot tables have a column BName. I want to create a slicer with field BName that controls all the pivots. I tried using report connections but it isn't showing all the pivot tables. It is only showing the one pivot table that I inserted the slicer for.

Comment: This will require a small amount of VBA code. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599449/vba-to-connect-slicers-looking-for-improvements-to-code/39604425#39604425